# Pass the id number in the link using nuxt-link

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on small project using nuxt.js and i would like to create a link to my products varints using `<nuxt-link to="">`  and i don't know how can i pass the id of the product that i get from the database i tried with  but i get an error.

what should i do ? this is my code :

```
<tr v-for="product in variables.laravelData.data" :key="product.id">
              <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="">
              </td>
              <td><img src="images/ui/thumb.jpg" width="38" height="38" alt=""></td>
              <td>
                <nuxt-link to="/products/variants/{{product.id}}">
                  {{ product.product_name }}
                </nuxt-link>
              </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 12):

You should to bind the `to` directive to write a dynamic id using `template strings`, as below:

```
<nuxt-link :to="`/products/variants/${product.id}`">
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this work?

```
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'name-of-your-router', params: { id: product.id } }">
```

According to this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1546#issuecomment-326267738 :

> If you want to use params you need to use name and not path:

```
<nuxt-link :to="{name: 'post-detail-id', params: { id:idPost } }">{{title}}</nuxt-link>
```

> You can see the name for each route into .nuxt/router.js

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me at
pages/posts/_slug/index.vue

params

```
<nuxt-link
  :to="{ name: 'posts-slug', params: { slug: slug, id: id }}"      
  class="btn btn-primary"
>
```

query

```
 <nuxt-link
      :to="{ path: '/posts/' + slug, query: { id: id}}"      
      class="btn btn-primary"
    >
```

http://localhost:3000/posts/fuga-dicta-qui-cum-reiciendis-et-eaque?id=10

https://nuxtjs.org/guides/context.svg